# JSON object and Spring @RequestParam

Tags: java, json, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I'm manipulating the following JSON object in my website frontend

```
<script>
window.campaign = {
    name: "test",
    budget: 20.00,
    type: 0,
    dynamic: false,
    geo_target: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27],
    time_target: {
        monday: ["00","00","00","00",1],
        tuesday: ["00","00","00","00",1],
        wednesday: ["00","00","00","00",1],
        thursday: ["00","00","00","00",1],
        friday: ["00","00","00","00",1],
        saturday: ["00","00","00","00",1],
        sunday: ["00","00","00","00",1]
    },

    setName: function(val) {
        this.name = val;
    },

    //some more setters go here
}
</script>
```

Then I send it to my Spring application using AJAX

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: submit_url, data: JSON.stringify(window.campaign) })
.done(function() { alert( "success" ); })
.fail(function() { alert( "error" ); });
```

Now the problem is mapping all the variables accordingly in my `@Controller`

```
....
@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "") String name,
@RequestParam(value = "budget", required = false, defaultValue = "0") BigDecimal budget,
@RequestParam(value = "type", required = false, defaultValue = "0") int type,
@RequestParam(value = "dynamic", required = false, defaultValue = "false") boolean dynamic,
@RequestParam(value = "geo_target", required = false, defaultValue = "") int[] geoTargeting,
....
```

This all works fine, but I have no idea how to map the `time_target`

I tried creating a new `Model` and mapping it using `@RequestBody`

```
....
@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "") String name,
....
@RequestParam(value = "geo_target", required = false, defaultValue = "") int[] geoTargeting,    
@RequestBody TimeTarget timeTargeting
....
```

with no success. I used http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org to create a `Class` for the whole object I'm sending, but no success whatsoever (just FYI, it created two classes, one for timeTargeting and one for everything else).

I'm getting really desperate. Help, please :) If the code provided is not enough, I can update with more.

Comment: 1 solution: `@RequestParam(value = "time_target") String[] timeTargeting ` this work for you ?

Comment: This controller is going to get really messy. You could just send the whole JSON string in one POST parameter. Then in your backend, you use a simple JSON library to parse the string and get the data out of it.

Comment: I even doubt it works. You are posting JSON not request parameters (afaik). Just send the JSON as a body, create an object and map all parameters to that object (jackson will do that for you).

Comment: M. Deinum or @mumpitz can one of you post an answer with an example? I tried that, but really got confused from irrelevant examples I found online...

Comment: You can use a converter like Jackson to transform from string to Java object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a wrapper around your JSON structure in Java and pass it through to the controller as a @RequestBody. Here is what worked for me:

```
public class CampaignDTO {
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal budget;
    private Integer type;
    private Boolean dynamic;

    @JsonProperty("geo_target")
    private List<Integer> geoTarget;

    @JsonProperty("time_target")
    private TimeTarget timeTarget;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public BigDecimal getBudget() {
        return budget;
    }

    public void setBudget(BigDecimal budget) {
        this.budget = budget;
    }

    public Integer getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(Integer type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Boolean getDynamic() {
        return dynamic;
    }

    public void setDynamic(Boolean dynamic) {
        this.dynamic = dynamic;
    }

    public List<Integer> getGeoTarget() {
        return geoTarget;
    }

    public void setGeoTarget(List<Integer> geoTarget) {
        this.geoTarget = geoTarget;
    }

    public TimeTarget getTimeTarget() {
        return timeTarget;
    }

    public void setTimeTarget(TimeTarget timeTarget) {
        this.timeTarget = timeTarget;
    }
}
```

Another DTO which is included in the CampainDTO:

```
public class TimeTarget {
    private List<String> monday;
    private List<String> tuesday;
    private List<String> wednesday;
    private List<String> thursday;
    private List<String> friday;
    private List<String> sunday;

    public List<String> getMonday() {
        return monday;
    }

    public void setMonday(List<String> monday) {
        this.monday = monday;
    }

    public List<String> getTuesday() {
        return tuesday;
    }

    public void setTuesday(List<String> tuesday) {
        this.tuesday = tuesday;
    }

    public List<String> getWednesday() {
        return wednesday;
    }

    public void setWednesday(List<String> wednesday) {
        this.wednesday = wednesday;
    }

    public List<String> getThursday() {
        return thursday;
    }

    public void setThursday(List<String> thursday) {
        this.thursday = thursday;
    }

    public List<String> getFriday() {
        return friday;
    }

    public void setFriday(List<String> friday) {
        this.friday = friday;
    }

    public List<String> getSunday() {
        return sunday;
    }

    public void setSunday(List<String> sunday) {
        this.sunday = sunday;
    }
}
```

And the last part is your controller. Note that here it works as an echo - it returns exactly what you posted. That's why I added @ResponseBody here.

```
@Controller
public class CampainController {

    @RequestMapping(name = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public CampaignDTO test(@RequestBody CampaignDTO campaignDTO) {
        return campaignDTO;
    }
}
```

After you post your request to http://localhost:8080/test it should work properly.

Comment: Worked just fine. However, I had to change the `ajax` call a bit to include Content-Type: "application/json"

Comment: I arrived here while searching for different ways to solve a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49101657/spring-data-rest-call-to-save-receiving-object-with-null-variable) I just posted here. This solution looked like it would work for me, but it didn't. The objects the `save` method receives have variables that are `String`s containing URLs to other objects in the database. Any controller method I implement fail to convert these URLs. This conversion works in extended default repository methods, but the front end can't reach custom save repository methods.