# Spring Data REST call to `save` receiving object with null variable

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data

I'm continuing the development of a system that uses the React JavaScript library (and related stuff) on the front end and Spring Data REST, Hibernate, PostgreSQL and related stuff on the back end.

This system will be used by people who may own one or more companies and their clients. This means that most/all model objects will have a reference to the `Company`(ies) that they belong to. Also, company owners will have a few `Employee`s that will have higher level access on this system (or these will be the owners themselves).

I need to implement a functionality where, when a company is inserted in the database, an employee is inserted as well. Also, if one fails, both must fail. Because of how the model was set up, I'm sending an `Employee` object to be saved, and, within it, the new `Company`, like this (using Axios):

```
employee: {
    // ...,
    company: {
        // ....
    }
}
```

Problem is, when the `save` method is called in the back end, the `Company` member of the `Employee` object is `null`. I've tried a few things, like messing with the relationship, adding an `Employee` list to the `Company` object, passing the `Company` object separately, but nothing worked.

What else could I try? Here are some classes:

#### Record.java

```
package xxx.model.common;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Record {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "deleted")
    protected Boolean isDeleted = false;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "enabled")
    protected Boolean isEnabled = true;
}
```

#### Company.java

```
package xxx.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.AttributeOverride;
import javax.persistence.AttributeOverrides;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import xxx.common.Record;
// ...

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
@Entity
@Table(name="company")
@AttributeOverrides( { @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "id_company")) } )
public class Company extends Record {

    /*
     * ...
     */

    // Necessary for Hibernate
    protected Company() {}

    public Company(/* ... */) {
        /*
         * ...
         */
    }
}
```

#### Registry.java

```
package xxx.model.common;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Registry extends Record {

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "code", length = 15)
    protected String code;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "name", length = 40)
    protected String name;
}
```

#### RegistrySingleCompany.java

```
package xxx.model.common;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import xxx.model.Company;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
@MappedSuperclass
public class RegistrySingleCompany extends Registry {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE }, optional= false)
    @JoinColumn(name="id_company")
    protected Company company;
}
```

#### Employee.java

```
package xxx.model;

import javax.persistence.AttributeOverride;
import javax.persistence.AttributeOverrides;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import xxx.model.common.RegistrySingleCompany;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
@AttributeOverrides( { @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "id_employee")) } )
public class Employee extends RegistrySingleCompany {

    /*
     * ...
     */

    // Necessary for Hibernate
    protected Employee() {}
}
```

#### EmployeeRepositoryCustom.java

```
package xxx.repository.custom;

import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import xxx.model.Employee;

public interface EmployeeRepositoryCustom {

    <S extends Employee> S save(S entity);
}
```

#### EmployeeRepositoryCustomImpl.java

```
package xxx.repository.custom;

import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;

import xxx.model.Employee;

public class EmployeeRepositoryCustomImpl implements EmployeeRepositoryCustom {

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public <S extends Employee> S save(@RequestBody S entity) {
        /*
         * ...
         */
        return entity;
    }
}
```

#### EmployeeProjection.java

```
package xxx.model.projection;

import org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.Projection;

import xxx.model.Employee;

@Projection(name = "employeeProjection", types = { Employee.class }) 
public interface EmployeeProjection {

    Boolean getIsDeleted();

    Boolean getIsEnabled();

    String getCode();

    String getName();

    /*
     * ...
     */
}
```

#### EmployeeRepository.java

```
package xxx.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

import xxx.model.Employee;
import xxx.model.projection.EmployeeProjection;
import xxx.repository.custom.EmployeeRepositoryCustom;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "employee", path = "employees", excerptProjection = EmployeeProjection.class)
public interface EmployeeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Employee, Long>, EmployeeRepositoryCustom {}
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** added missing classes.

Comment: where you map employee to company entity @ManyToOne relationship ?

Comment: In `RegistrySingleCompany`, since `Employee` extends that.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, one of the things I tried was to add an `Employee` list inside the `Company` object, which implies using `Company`'s repository instead of the `Employee`'s one to save both objects, but the other object was also arriving null. However, my colleague found out that, by using `exported = false` inside `@RepositoryRestResource()`, the value would be received correctly.

That would screw other things up, so we found the following temporary solution:

- Create an `exported = false` repository (`EmployeeWrapper`) for the sole purpose of delivering the necessary `Employee` data to construct a new one inside `save`.
- Instead of adding an `Employee` list inside `Company`, add an `EmployeeWrapper` list.
- `EmployeeWrapper` also references `Company`.

We're still working on a more correct approach.

**Update:** a more correct approach:

My colleague also found out that, by adding a `@Transient` `Employee` list to `Company`, it's possible to receive the correctly filled out `Employee` object to save it. I don't know if it works at the repository since, due to other constraints, we moved to use a `@RepositoryRestController` and are receiving the `Company` as `@RequestBody org.springframework.hateoas.Resource<Company> resource`.

We still want to find a better solution, because an `Employee` list inside `Company` wasn't planned in our model and, worse yet, we're needing to use list of other things for other methods.

**Update:** an even better approach:

Experimenting a little more, we created a POJO containing the entities that we needed and received that in the controller, same way as before. Works well.

We're still not satisfied, though. Ideally, we want to receive the `Employee` to be saved, with the `Company` to be saved inside it, and save them both at once.