# Test PUT request with JSON causes transmitted data to be null

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have following problem. If I try to test the PUT request in Android Studio this is working :

I'm using Android Studio to test the request and spring-boot

```
PUT http://localhost:8080/api/v1/products/3?price=800
Content-Type: application/json
```

But if I try to do it with a json :

```
###
PUT http://localhost:8080/api/v1/products/3
Content-Type: application/json

{
 "price" :800
}
```

I get following error:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2023-06-21T20:00:23.051+00:00",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "Cannot invoke \"java.lang.Double.doubleValue()\" because \"price\" is null",
  "path": "/api/v1/products/3"
}
```

Does someone has an idea where this can come from ? Thank you in advance

My Endpoint:

```
@PutMapping(path = "/{productId}")
    public void updateStudent(
        @PathVariable("productId") Long productId,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String title,
        @RequestParam(required = false) Double price,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String description,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String category,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String image
    )
    {
        productService.updateProduct(productId,title,price,description,category,image);
    }
```

I expect that the the request is proceed

Comment: How have you defined your endpoint? First guess is that you have it looking for a query parameter "price" and it being null causes your issue. Query parameters are not interchangeable with JSON body request data.

Comment: `@PutMapping(path = "/{productId}")
    public void updateStudent(
        @PathVariable("productId") Long productId,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String title,
        @RequestParam(required = false) Double price,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String description,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String category,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String image
    )
    {
        productService.updateProduct(productId,title,price,description,category,image);
    }` @Chris

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44553356/496099 and https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-send-json-parameters but in short, you can't do what you are trying to do, not like that anyway as RequestParam is used for path parameters to help with GET requests. Pass in a DTO for JSON handling (you marked this with the JPA tag, so an entity is likely your end result anyway)

Answer (score 0):

For handling that json content you need to change the signature of your method as a @RequestParam wouldn't work that way, use a @RequestBody instead as stated by spring docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html
where it says this annotation indicates a method parameter should be bound to the body of the web request, so the change might look like this:

```
@PutMapping(path = "/{productId}")
public void updateProduct(
    @PathVariable("productId") Long productId,
    @RequestBody ProductUpdateDto updateDto) {

    productService.updateProduct(productId, <values From The Dto like updateDto.getPrice()>);
}
```

With this kind of implementation you need to provide a ProductUpdateDto class which will encapsulate the data required to be Put.

So a sample ProductUpdateDto class might be:

```
public class ProductUpdateDto {
    private Double price;

    // Getter and setter for the price field
    // Additional fields can be added as per the request payload structure
}
```